# Compiling bitcoin error : A compiler with support for C++17 language features is required

Tags: bitcoin-core, compiling, c++, mastering-bitcoin

I am reading the "Mastering bitcoin: Programming the Open Blockchain" book by Andreas Antonopolous. In the chapter about compiling bitcoin, the instructions were to execute first

```
./autogen.sh
```

and the output was

```
glibtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, 'build-aux'.
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/ltmain.sh'
glibtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'build-aux/m4'.
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/libtool.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/ltoptions.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/ltsugar.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/ltversion.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
configure.ac:45: installing 'build-aux/compile'
configure.ac:28: installing 'build-aux/missing'
Makefile.am: installing 'build-aux/depcomp'
glibtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, 'build-aux'.
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/ltmain.sh'
glibtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'build-aux/m4'.
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/libtool.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/ltoptions.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/ltsugar.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/ltversion.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
configure.ac:36: warning: The macro `AC_PROG_CC_C89' is obsolete.
configure.ac:36: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/c.m4:1652: AC_PROG_CC_C89 is expanded from...
configure.ac:36: the top level
configure.ac:15: installing 'build-aux/compile'
configure.ac:9: installing 'build-aux/missing'
Makefile.am: installing 'build-aux/depcomp'
glibtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, 'build-aux'.
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/ltmain.sh'
glibtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'build-aux/m4'.
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/libtool.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/ltoptions.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/ltsugar.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/ltversion.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
configure.ac:812: warning: $as_echo is obsolete; use AS_ECHO(["message"]) instead
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
build-aux/m4/ax_pthread.m4:89: AX_PTHREAD is expanded from...
configure.ac:812: the top level
configure.ac:94: installing 'build-aux/compile'
configure.ac:48: installing 'build-aux/missing'
src/Makefile.am: installing 'build-aux/depcomp'
```

While the output aligned with expected output from the instructions, the next command

```
./configure
```

Exits with an error that C++17 isn't available from the compilers on the machine. The output was

```
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... ./build-aux/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C++... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for g++ option to enable C++11 features... none needed
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking whether g++ supports C++17 features with -std=c++17... no
checking whether g++ supports C++17 features with +std=c++17... no
checking whether g++ supports C++17 features with -h std=c++17... no
checking whether g++ supports C++17 features with -std=c++1z... no
checking whether g++ supports C++17 features with +std=c++1z... no
checking whether g++ supports C++17 features with -h std=c++1z... no
configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++17 language features is required.
```

and on running

```
g++ --version
```

gives

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-
dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

and `g++-11 --version`

gives

```
g++-11 (Homebrew GCC 11.2.0) 11.2.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Now both GNU GCC and also Clang compiler versions I have support both C++ 17 standard and the associated flags, why does this error happen?

I made sure my path is set correctly and also other cpp programs execute correctly. I am unable to find the mistake here. Can anyone please guide me?

This is my first question, first one even on stack exchange as a whole. Please excuse any obvious ideas I missed.

I am using the source from repo and version v22.0. Thanks!

Comment: Try the steps mentioned here: https://jonatack.github.io/articles/how-to-compile-bitcoin-core-and-run-the-tests

Comment: @Prayank tried that, still the same issue